# Zip Files using PeopleCode in Application Engine

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I have a requirment to zip multiple folders inside parent folder and display the file in App Engine ouput. The folder structure in Unix File Server - 
Parent Folder 
- Folder1 (contains files)
- Folder2 (contains files)

How to zip the folders and store it in parent folder using PeopleCode in AE (Final folder structure will be as follows
Parent Folder 
-Folder1
-Folder2
-ParentFolder.Zip.

Note: Process runs on Unix Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we were calling java code to zip files.

Such as:

```
    &buffer = CreateJavaArray("byte[]", 18024);
    &zipStream = CreateJavaObject("java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream", CreateJavaObject("java.io.FileOutputStream", &outDir | &outZip));
    For &i = 1 To &inFiles.Len
      &zipStream.putNextEntry(CreateJavaObject("java.util.zip.ZipEntry", &inFiles [&i]));
      &inStream = CreateJavaObject("java.io.FileInputStream", &outDir | &inFiles [&i]);
      &len = &inStream.read(&buffer);
      While &len > 0;
        &zipStream.write(&buffer, 0, &len);
        &len = &inStream.read(&buffer);
      End-While;
      &zipStream.closeEntry();
      &inStream.close();
    End-For;

   &zipStream.close();
```